# Why is my system getting these white bars around windows?

Tags: unity, nvidia, graphics

I'm running NVIDIA Optimus on a laptop (960M with Intel graphics), but my system occasionally will display like this:

[image: My Dumb Error]

This seems to happen most often after a relatively long sleep, but can usually be resolved with something like `unity --reload` or similar. This issue has been known to appear on right-click menus, indicator menus, basically anything that has a shadow, and even buttons at times. However, it never seems to appear on popup notifications from Unity, which is strange.

I'm running NVIDIA's proprietary driver (version 378.09) and kernel 4.4.0-62-generic, however this issue was also present on older kernels (4.4.0-59).

Is there anything I can do to permanently resolve this issue?

---

(Relevant) output of `lspci -k`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell Skylake Integrated Graphics
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Dell GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: You have both unsupported kernel and Nvidia drivers. Try with the current `4.4.0-59` kernel and Nvidia driver from Ubuntu repos. You can report it as a bug.

Comment: @Pilot6 The kernel is from `xenial-proposed`, though I can assure you that this happens on kernel 4.4.0-59 and the older NVIDIA drivers (which is why I upgraded to the proposed versions).

Comment: Report it as a bug then.

Comment: @Pilot6 Would this bug be against the kernel, the NVIDIA drivers, or Unity? All three seem to be involved here.

Comment: Either kernel or drivers.

Comment: BTW, please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command. And does it happen on Intel or Nvidia?

Comment: @Pilot6 I haven't seen the issue when the Intel card is enabled (though I do see a complete drop of performance).