# Display abnormal after wake up from suspend

Tags: graphics, display, gpu-driver

My display is all right when my Ubuntu restart.

However, if my system wakes up from suspend mode, it display as below with many broken point and strip surround the window:

[image: Screen display after suspend]

Can you help me please?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using and what system do you have?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1292830) and is [in fact known about on this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879113/why-is-my-system-getting-these-white-bars-around-windows).

Now, while we wait for an actual resolution for this issue, there is something that can be done to temporarily work around this bug.

Put simply, just hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type the command `unity`. Hit enter, and the desktop will restart.

Note that this may crash certain programs (namely, Google Chrome), but it will restore your desktop to a normal state.

---

Alternatively, as this is a NVIDIA bug, you can also take a few more permanent workarounds:

- If you're running NVIDIA Prime, you can swap over to the Intel card. Note, however, that this will cause a performance drop.
- Downgrade to NVIDIA driver 367.57 as described [in this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1292830/comments/89).
- If you want to experiment a bit, add the PPA [`ppa:kaihengfeng/lp1292830`](https://launchpad.net/~kaihengfeng/+archive/ubuntu/lp1292830) (from [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1292830/comments/90)). Then, run the following command (followed by a reboot or restart of the X server):

  ```
  sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
  ```